# Building another TableViewCell when tap on button

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic-programming

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellButton.identifier(), for: indexPath) as! CellButton
            cell.build(height: 40, color: .lighterGray())
            cell.blockAction = {
                let category = categories?[indexPath.row]
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
             CellCheck.identifier(), for: indexPath) as! 
            CellCheck 
           }
 return cell
```

This is the code I have and when blockAction called (function called when i tap button in cell) I need to build another TableViewCell and remove first that appear

Is there any way of loading it inside same cell and also expand the height by the height of dynamic cell content

Comment: The tag - "dynamic-programming" is not related to the problem which you have.I suggested an edit for the same yesterday, which was approved by two other members but it seems you rejected it. Could you kindly review your decision ?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove IndexPath and then add add a new indexPath.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

private var buttonTapped: Bool = false
private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if buttonTapped == true,
        let olderIndexPath = selectedIndexPath,
        selectedIndexPath == olderIndexPath {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.callback = {[weak self] in
        self?.buttonTapped = true
        self?.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        self?.insertNewCell(indexPath)
    }
    return cell
}

private func insertNewCell(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
    tableView.endUpdates()

}
}
```